# Should I use Mutex OR Critical Section for Windows Mobile RIL

Tags: winapi, geolocation, windows-mobile, ril

I am using [Radio Layer Interface (RIL) Native APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa923037.aspx) in [Windows Mobile application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd938890.aspx#RetrievingLocationInformationthroughCellTowerLookup). In this API, the return values / results of most functions are not returned immediately but are passed through a callback function which is passed to the RIL API.

Some usage examples are found at [XDA Develompent Tools](http://nah6.com/~itsme/cvs-xdadevtools/itsutils/dll/rilfunc.h) and [Google](http://gears.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gears/geolocation/device_data_provider.h) [Gears](http://gears.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gears/geolocation/radio_data_provider_wince.cc) [Geolocation](http://gears.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gears/geolocation/) [API](http://code.google.com/apis/gears/api_geolocation.html).

My question is, in these two examples, a mutex is used to guard the data instead of other synchronization objects.

Now, will Critical Section do fine here in the use cases described by both examples? Which thread or process will actually call the callback functions?

**Edit:**
My data is accessed by my codes only from inside my process but which thread/process is calling the callback functions in RIL API? I mean, I passed a function callback to the RIL API, but are the callbacks called from other process? in that case, it will give another explanation why the samples are using Mutex. If the RIL API actually creates a thread inside my process and it calls my callback functions, then I think Critical Section would be fine (and it's faster than a mutex).

**Update:**
I have data which is **(1)** accessed by my codes from within my own process and is also **(2)** modified from a function callback. The callback is done by RIL API.

My Question: Which thread/process is calling the callback functions in RIL API?

The Story so far:
*Me:* Hi Mr RIL, please put some data into my office (a.k.a variables).
*RIL:* OK Sir. I will put the data later and I will signal you when it is done (I used an event here).

An access card is required to enter my office. If Mr RIL is from the same company as me, Mr RIL can use his own access card to enter my office (in my case, it means a Critical Section). If he is from other companies, I will need to set up an access card/visitor card for him (in my case, I need a mutex here).

If Mr RIL uses his own access card, it means I don't need to set up an access card/visitor card for him and that means less trouble for me. (i.e. Critical Section is faster than a Mutex)

The problem is, I just met this Mr RIL a few days ago and I don't know much about him. I don't know if he is from the same company as me. One option as [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2482710/109747) by *[nobugz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/)* is to set up an access card for Mr RIL regardless whether Mr RIL is from the same company as me. This way, Mr RIL is guaranteed to be able to enter my office. (my data/variables are guaranteed to be safe)

Right now I use mutex in my code (set up a possibly redundant access card for Mr RIL).

Aha! Just got an idea when writing this. I think I will just ask Mr RIL from which company he is. That way, I don't have to set up access card for him in the future if he turns out to be in the same company as me. (i.e. put `GetCurrentProcessId()` and `GetCurrentThreadId()` in the callback function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Windows Mobile RIL normally resides in device.exe (for WM6.x). However, when your process invokes the RIL, your call passes via the RIL Proxy.

The RIL proxy is linked with, and resides in your process, and handles all of the issues associated with process boundaries for you (as an aside, this is at least part of the reason why all RIL data structures need to be packed into a single block of memory of known size). Internally the RIL Proxy creates a thread on which your callback is executed.

This means that your code can use a CRITICAL_SECTION object to provide the necessary synchronization/protection.

Comment: Great answer! I have been waiting for this kind of answer.

Answer (score 1):

The point of using the mutex is that you don't know what thread might make the callback.  Yes, a critical section would work too.  Careful, getting it wrong causes random and *very* hard to diagnose failure.

Answer (score 1):

A critical section *is* a mutex. A critical section is different from a normal mutex (at least primarily) in one way: it's specific to one process, where a mutex can be used across processes.

So, in this case, the basic question is exactly what you're protecting -- if it's the data inside your program, that won't be accessible to another process, then a critical section should do the job nicely. If you're protecting something that would be shared by the two processes if the user were to run two instances of your program at once, then you probably need a mutex.

Edit: As far as having to use a critical section to protect what RIL itself does, no, that isn't (or at least definitely *shouldn't*) be needed. With a mutex, you're counting on all the processes cooperate by opening a mutex with the same name to control access to the shared resource(s). You can't count on that, so if it is needed the interface is completely broken.

Update: unless they're doing something really unusual in RIL, the callback will happen within your process, so a critical should be adequate. If it's modifying your data, that means your data is mapped and visible to that code -- which means the data in the data in the critical section will also be mapped and visible, and it'll work. The time a critical section doesn't work is when you're dealing with separate processes, so the data in one isn't mapped/visible to the other.

Answer (score 0):

Well, one other difference between a mutex and a critical section (Windows implementations, of course) is that a critical section is re-entrant - i.e. the same thread can acquire the critical section twice without having to release it.